# Installing Xubuntu to Flash Drive

Tags: usb, xubuntu, persistent

How can I make a persistent install of Xubuntu on my flash drive, so I can boot from my flash drive and save changes and files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [How-to Geek has an article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/) on how to do this for Ubuntu. Presumably you can substitute the Xubuntu disc image and it would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install it as it where any harddisk. Boot the installation media, when asked for harddisk choose the usb drive. Make sure your BIOS will/can boot usb devices. Might need 'rootdelay=10' or so on the kernel line (in grub) to delay boot a bit so usb stuff is initialized in kernel before accessing root system.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat easy way to do it is to unplug/turnoff main HDD(s) in your system then plug-in the USB Drive and perform an ordinary installation on the USB Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com). They have tons of tutorials for installing linux distros to usb drives, including [this one on Xubuntu](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-xubuntu-904-persistent-install-windows/). :)

Also, if you are unframiliar with a 'persistent' install you may want to [give this a read](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/).