# How I can create a multiplatform portable pendrive of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, portable

The goal is to carry a pendrive with your personal files and Ubuntu. Just plug in a computer and boot it.

Is this possible?

Across Mac/Windows/Linux?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Xubuntu to Flash Drive](http://superuser.com/questions/28210/installing-xubuntu-to-flash-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [YUMI from pen drive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-2.0.1.5.exe). It makes it very easy, and does not require installation. I am typing this from a computer that is booted off a flash drive with ubuntu and windows 7.

[image: YUMI]

Comment: Lol, I didn't know you can just do that. I can carry all my maintenance tools everywhere! But I have mac, any alternative?

Comment: You can still boot from this on a mac. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201663 Connect the device, then select it in Startup Disk preferences. Or, connect the device, restart, and immediately press and hold the Option key to access Startup Manager.

Comment: What I mean from that is that I dont have a windows computer to run YUMI, but I'll run a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's website details how to do this with Pendrive Linux's Universal USB installer. You can find that here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
For a more portable version, I might recommend using 32-bit Ubuntu for usage with 32-bit CPUs.

Comment: Welcome to Super User, CoffeeFrame! In its current form, your answer isn't much more than a link to an outside website. From the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer): "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Answers with a good summary of the external resource are more likely to earn you reputation, which grants you additional privileges.